# Code::Blocks Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe Failed

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, execution

yesterday I opened up Code::Blocks after a month or so of not using it, and I was messing around, writing some test code in C++. I compiled some programs correctly, then all of a sudden I got an error that I can't seem to solve:

> -------------- Build: Debug in asdfsdfsdgf (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\aharman\Documents\CPP\asdfsdfsdgf\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
> Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c C:\Users\aharman\Documents\CPP\asdfsdfsdgf\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o' in 'C:\Users\aharman\Documents\CPP\asdfsdfsdgf' failed.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't recall making any changes to anything related to Code::Blocks, so I don't know why it suddenly stopped working. I've been doing hours of research, and I just can't find the solution. Creating a thread is always a last resort for me, when I have given up trying to find an answer because it seems hopeless. Does anybody know what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work on another project? Reinstall Code::Blocks and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but nothing changed.

Comment: That is, It doesn't work with any project. I tried reinstalling earlier, but nothing changed.

Comment: And if you clean the workspace? (I believe it's a button in the IDE)

Comment: Hmm... That didn't appear to do anything. Another thing, if I press Run instead of Build, I get "It seems this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?" When I hit Yes, it tries and fails to build it, and it just pops up repeatedly until I hit no.

Comment: Try installing CodeLite with MinGW. If the problem persists then it's probably something in your windows.

Comment: Okay, I'll try CodeLite.

Comment: Yay, CodeLite is working fine. Guess I'll stick with it for now.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that Code::Blocks is not looking in the correct location. First i recommend going to setting - compiler and debugger - toolchain executables. Then within Compiler's installation directory click Auto detect. Press OK and then try again. I hope this helped. Goobyebye.

Comment: I already did that, but it just chose the directory I already have selected.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rename the file to `mingw32-g++` : `C:\mingw64\bin` => find a file with `-g++` in the end, make sure to save a current name, then rename it to `mingw32-g++`, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

These solution above doesn't work for me so after couple of hours I figured what actually is going wrong.

There are two directories for mingw one located in c:\MinGW and other same in c:\programme files(×86)\codeblocks\ MinGW

So what's happening your live written script which you want to run is getting compiled in code blocks directory and the compiler plugin is somewhere else.

Change by going to Settings > Compiler and selected "toolchain executables and select bin directory present inside
c:\programme files(×86)\codeblocks\ MinGW

And select appropriate extension gcc or mingw32-g++

Now it will compile default work file inside codeblock "Hello world"

Restart the software and open your project again to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

So what solved the problem for me is this:

I went to Settings > Compiler and selected "toolchain executables" I went down to C compiler and clicked on the directory and re-selected "mingw32-g++.exe" and clicked "Open", it has give me an error "the file couldn't be find, because the names of the exe programs, that the codeblocks requires, and the names of files that is in the foulder "MinGW" can some different and the program can't find these exe files.

I believe the software experienced problems finding mingw32-g++.exe So all I had to do is to re-selected it.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on your project > properties > build targets. Look in the box labeled "Build Target Files" and ensure that the correct source files are selected.

Answer (score 0):

So what solved the problem for me is this:

I went to Settings > Compiler and selected "toolchain executables"
I went down to C compiler and clicked on the directory and re-selected "mingw32-g++.exe" and clicked "Open" and I Run the project again and it worked just fine.

I believe the software experienced problems finding mingw32-g++.exe
So all I had to do is to re-selected it.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with codeblocks 20.03 nosetup32bit version. g++.exe in bin folder is 64bit.

edit: yep if your version is win32 the most probably the problem with g++ executable which is x64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with a little debugging I understood that "Linker for dynamic libs" has the wrong file name path. 
Solution:- Go to `Settings` -> `Compiler` -> `Toolchain executables` -> in the `Linker` for dynamic libs: The default one is actually not at all present in the path. So select the one that is actually present. 
So the new `Linker for dynamic libs` will have `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`.

This should work.